# How to return to Fragment thats call registerForActivityResult after back pressed

Tags: android, back-button, android-architecture-navigation, startactivityforresult, registerforactivityresult

When I call `mPickFromGalleryLauncher.launch(PICK_FROM_GALLERY_INPUT)` gallery is opened. If in gallery I press back button application is closed.

How can I return to Fragment from gallery? Application use SingleActivity pattern with Android Navigation Component.

My Fragment:

```
class ImagesFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_images) {

    private val mPickFromGalleryLauncher by uiLazy {
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
            // handle uri
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        pickFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener {
            mPickFromGalleryLauncher.launch("image/*")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've just checked your code, and it works fine for me. When I press back, I'm taken back to my app with `Fragment`s intact.

Comment: I found an answer... Maybe this is my mistake cause `uri` can be null and there is `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: it must not be null. `ActivityResultCallback::onActivityResult` can pass `null` as parameter.